# How to make a shortcode for my WP_Query Loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a noob Wordpress Developer and I just created my first Custom Template Page using Advanced Custom Fields and managed to loop.

```
        <?php 
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'art',
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );         
        ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?> 

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'art' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

But I will like to use it not only inside a template page, but anywhere I want. Therefore I need to create a shortcode.

Example:

```
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

My question would be: How can i put the loop inside my shortcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
function foobar_func( $atts ) {
global $post;
$output = '';
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'art',
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,

);
$fe_query= new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $fe_query->have_posts() ) {
    $output .= '<ul class="fe-query-results-shortcode-output">';
    while ( $fe_query->have_posts() ) {
        $fe_query->the_post();

        $title = get_the_title();
        $link = get_the_permalink();

        $output .= "<li><a href=\"{$link}\">{$title}</a></li>";
       }
       $output .= '</ul>';
      } else {
     $output .= '<div class="fe-query-results-shortcode-output-none">No      results were found</div>';
    }

wp_reset_postdata();
return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function loop_art() {
       ob_start();
       get_template_part('loop_art');
       return ob_get_clean();   
    } 
    add_shortcode( 'loop_art', 'loop_art' );
?>

<?php 
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'art',
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                );
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );         

            if ($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post()
                   ?>   

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">

        <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <p>Price: $<?php the_field('price'); ?></p>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">

        <p><img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" alt="Example image of <?php the_title(); ?>"></p>


    </div><!-- .entry-content -->   

</article>

              <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```