# how to get featured image from custom post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm using this code to get featured image from post. This is my whole code every thing else is working rather than the image i'm trying to display featured image also the posttype i'm using is custom post type.
Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

```
    add_shortcode('get-video-post-type','videos_cpt');
function videos_cpt(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'Videos',
        'post_status'=>'publish',
    );
    $result = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($result -> have_posts()){
        while($result -> have_posts()){
            $result -> the_post();
        ?>
        <div id="show-all-post" class="posts-carousel">
            <div class="item" id="video-box">
                <div class="left-img"><img class="post-image" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() , 'full' ); ?>" alt="image"></div> 
                <div class="right-content">
                    <h1 style="color:black;"><?php the_title();?></h1>
                    <p style="color:black;"><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,50); ?>....</p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this one:

```
<img class="post-image" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');?>" alt="image">
```

Comment: I've tried this too but nothing happens , can you please tell me about $post_ID

Comment: You can use $post_ID to get_the_ID()

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Now, you can try by removed full img tag and use <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
Please add **echo** with get_the_post_thumbnail() function and add get_the_ID() instead of $post_ID variable.

<img class="post-image" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() , 'full' ); ?>" alt="image">

It will be defiantly work. It is working in my WordPress setup. 

Check with this reference link:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/
```

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: @Sonali debug the code where you will get the post id and pass into the get_the_post_thumbnail function.

Comment: did you tried  the_ID() instead of  get_the_ID(). Please try this one.

Comment: Still not showing the image, I've added the whole code above please have a look

Comment: Debug the get_the_ID() and the_ID() where post id coming or not, then we can fix.

Comment: Check with that reference: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119093/how-to-make-a-shortcode-for-my-wp-query-loop

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<?php $bg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );?>
<div class="left-img"><img class="post-image" src="<?php echo $bg[0];?>" alt="image"></div>
```